# mysql select random from results

Tags: mysql

I have one table test like that:

```
real_id    name   active
1           A       0
2           B       1
3           C       1
4           D       1
5           E       0
6           F       1
```

What I looking for is:

Select rows having active column = 1 and finally get only one random from them

I have tried that:

```
/*get the max count from recordset*/
SET @rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE active = 1);
set @fakeId = 0;

SELECT * FROM test, (
    SELECT *, @fakeId := @fakeId + 1 AS fake_id,  
    (ROUND((RAND() * (@rows_count-1))+1)) AS random_nr
    FROM test
    WHERE active = 1
) AS total
WHERE total.fake_id = total.random_nr;
LIMIT 1;
```

At first sight it seem working good, but if I have tried them several , I have no results from time to time

**SOLVED**

I have solved them by calculate the random_nr outside of select into a variable

```
SET @random_nr = (ROUND((RAND() * (@rows_count-1))+1));
```

And in WHERE clause

```
WHERE total.fake_id = @random_nr;
```

Comment: What's wrong with select ... from... where... order by rand() limit 1?

Comment: As I read in other answers order by random () it seems to have performace problems on large tables. (The table I put was just an example I actually want to use it for large tables)

Comment: Your question isn't about performance

Comment: Yes you are right but, I was hoping for some help on the code that I put. I have not thought that someone will suggest order by random (). Sorry

Comment: Well, you got that wrong then ;-)

Comment: + one for the good mood ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from test where active = 1 order by rand() limit 1
```

Comment: As I read in other answers order by random () it seems to have performace problems on large tables. (The table I put was just an example I actually want to use it for large tables)

Comment: @MTK how large is your table?

Comment: Can be up to 10 000 000 rows ... For the moment I have found one solution ( I have edited mi question ) ... But if you have better other solution be welcome